# как задать поле класса в параметр по умолчанию метода

Tags: c++

как задать поле класса в параметр по умолчанию метода?

```
class Curl{
private:
    std::string url;
public:
    std::string readUrl(std::string Url = (?) );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Curl{
private:
    std::string url;
public:
    std::string readUrl()  //сделали метод без параметров,
                           //который вызывает уже метод с 
                           //параметром, в качестве которого
                           //передается поле класса


    {
         return readUrl(url);
    }
    std::string readUrl(const std::string& url);
};
```

Comment: я так и сделал. Просто интересно было на будущее, возможно ли сделать как я написал в вопросе